# Problems finding human readable ascii text in log files

Tags: grep

I understand that assisting with college assignments is frowned upon here but I am seeking help with grep. I have been searching for answers online all day & am running out of time.
I have a zipped logparse file that I have unzipped - it contains over 1000 logs, I need to examine the contents of this file to obtain a 72 character human readable text from one of the log files, any grep command i run freezes my VM, losing time re-booting ect., I have attempted

```
grep --text <file>   
grep -a <file>   
grep -w <file>    

grep [char] <file>    returns a output stating text has been detected but again when i go to view via vi or vim it again crashes
```

any help greatly appreciated,
Sarah

Comment: There's also `zgrep`, which transparently inflates files when they are compressed. In any case, if something freezes your VM, that may be a problem with that VM and not with how you're using `grep`.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich - I'll try that

Comment: froze again, wonder is there any options without using grep?

Comment: Fix your VM! Also, I'm wondering what behaviour you interpret as "freezes my VM", which is very unspecific. It's always a good idea to provide details of what you did and what you observed, not just what you intended to achieve and how you interpret the actual behaviour.

Comment: `grep [--text|-a|-w] file` tells grep to _read standard input_ which defaults to the terminal, and look for data matching the regexp 'file'. **It's not frozen, it's waiting for input.** Type control+D and it will exit (without finding anything). To search for x in file, do `grep x file` -- but you have to define what x is; what exactly do you mean by 'human readable text'? What kind of text is _not_ human readable?

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C grep -Eo '[[:graph:]]{72}' *` in a directory containing only the unzipped files. Whitespace is not matched.

Comment: `grep -inHoar 'search text' ./` will search all\* files and print line numbers (\*except compressed)